# Rebasing/Renaming Branches Git

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have two branches, one is release branch and the other is a feature branch. I worked on both branches from when feature branch was created out of release branch, so merge is not going to work properly. There were a lot of changes in feature branch, from renaming files/folders,...

I tried to rebase feature branch to release branch, but it does not work, there are to many conflicts. Now I am thinking of renaming feature branch to release branch, but the problem is that we have tags, that were made from release branch.

What I would like to know is, if I rename feature branch to release branch, and delete release branch, will we lose the tags that were created on release branch?

Comment: You have 2 sets of changes that conflicts so you are going to throw away half of them ?

Comment: I want to throw away release changes, because they are irrelevant now.

Comment: Ok. then you can do what you proposed. Be carefull if you share this with anyone or have a remote. when you push your new release branch, you will probably need to use --force

Answer (score 1):

A tag is just a named label for a particular commit.  A tag is independent of any branches that you may have.  Deleting or renaming a branch will not cause tags to be lost or otherwise modified.